# Getting fatal error Allowed memory size exhausted in cakephp router

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, cakephp-2.3

I am getting this error in cakephp. When I upload fresh copy it runs perfectly but when I upload some plugin inside plugin folder it gives following error. Error is displayed on default action on home page.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /home1/allinal6/public_html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php on line 1088
```

Comment: Is it related to `jQuery` ?

Comment: Are the tags correct?

Comment: have u changed the memory limit and checked

Comment: please increase your memory size

Comment: php.ini is not working on my server

Comment: Yes I also changed the memory limit

Answer (score 0):

There might be something about the plugin that might be taking the memory to the limits.Check if there are any loop that are out of control.Try to debug the code by using each plugin one by one.And then find which plugin might be causing the error.For the time being you could increase the `memory limit` in your `php.ini` file